# Use Find/Replace to replace arbitrary text per line?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a bunch of object variables which are all initialised in their declarations such that:

```
Private _myObject As New ThisObject("SomeString")
```

where `ThisObject` is one of a number of object types, but all are initialised using a string.

I would like to use the Visual Studio Find/Replace dialog box to search for "`As New`" then replace everything from "`As New`" to the first set of speech marks with some text such that:

**EDIT**

My original example could be solved using other methods. This example is more representative of the actual problem:

```
Private _myObjectA As New ThisObjectA("SomeString")
Private _myObjectLongName As New ThisObjectLongName("SomeString")
```

changes to:

```
Private _myObjectA = [someCode]"SomeString")
Private _myObjectLongName = [someCode]"SomeString")
```

Obviously this would be doable in code, reading a text file, but I'm specifically asking about the capabilities of the Visual Studio Find/Replace dialog.

**OLD EXAMPLE:**

```
Private _myObjectA As New ThisObjectA("SomeString")
Private _myObjectB As New ThisObjectB("SomeString")
```

changes to:

```
Private _myObjectA = [someCode]"SomeString")
Private _myObjectB = [someCode]"SomeString")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in Visual Studio. However oddly enough, VS does not use the usual .NET Regex-syntax:
[image]

In VB you would write:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "New ThisObject\w*","[somecode]")
```

Comment: This is the best general solution. Kvn's solution would work very well (and fast) when your code lines up over the multiple lines that you're editing.

Comment: If did some research and noticed that the VS syntax for "\w" is not ":w", as I stated in my answer, but ":a". ":w" contains only letters, ":a" includes digits as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this sort of things easily using `Shift + Alt + Arrow keys` and `Ctl + K + \` with `Find/Replace`  dialog box. Refer [my blog](http://www.naveenbhat.in/2012/06/very-useful-uncommon-shortcuts-in.html) for more information.

**Update:** Follow the steps, as shown in the screen shot.

[image: Find-Replace]

Comment: unfortunately the blog is down! may I know the reason for down vote?

Comment: Because your blog post does not in any way refer to question I asked, and because my question has nothing to do with column-wise text selection, nor about removing whitespace.

Comment: It seems that you didn't understand what I mean! I have uploaded a screen shot for you, please check it.

Comment: Oh. I see what you mean, now. Unfortunately my actual code does not line up in this way, so your answer is not useful to my situation, but this is not clear from my original question. I shall change my question to better suit my situation. Apologies for my misunderstanding.

Comment: I appreciate how you bring to the attention the lesser known (and smart) ways of editing.